# Rails - How To Destroy Users Created Under Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, destroy

For my application, I have user accounts that people can sign up.  I use the `devise` gem for the setup.

I also have a users page that lists out all the users registered to the site along with a `destroy` link. I want my administrator to be able to delete users and have it redirected to this users listing page.  But when I click the link to destroy a specific user, it just redirects to the user profile page and does not delete the user from the database.

Does somebody know why?

**UPDATE: Updated code below as recommended and works now.

users_controller.rb

```
  def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.destroy

    if @user.destroy
        redirect_to root_url, notice: "User deleted."
    end
  end
```

users/index.html.erb

```
<div class = "container">
    <div id="usersview">
    <b>USERS DIRECTORY</b>
    <%= render @users %>
</div>

<center>
    <%= will_paginate @users %>
</center>
</div>
```

users/_user.html.erb

```
<div class="comments">
  <%= link_to user.name, user %>
  <% if current_user.try(:admin?) && !current_user?(user) %>
       <%= link_to "Destroy", admin_destroy_user_path(user), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

routes.rb

```
devise_for :users    
match 'users/:id' => 'users#destroy', :via => :delete, :as => :admin_destroy_user
match 'users/:id' => 'users#show', as: :user
resources :users
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Devise doesn't provide this functionality out of the box. You have created your own destroy action, but you also have to create a custom route to that action.

In your routes:

```
 match 'users/:id' => 'users#destroy', :via => :delete, :as => :admin_destroy_user
```

And then when creating the link:

```
<%= link_to "Destroy", admin_destroy_user_path(user), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
```

Comment: I updated (see question edited) as you noted but same results. Not destroying and routes to show page. Is it possible my routes are not in the right order?

Comment: try placing the custom route above the `devise_for` call.

Comment: I don't think you need the `resources :users`

Comment: I need resources :users for some "member do get:..." but the reorder works now, see updated code in question above.

Answer (score 6):

According to devise 4.1 rake routes and views, using the following will help you delete the account once logged in as a user.

```
<%= link_to "Cancel my account", registration_path(current_user), data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, method: :delete %>
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you have in your routes.rb: `resources :users`

The problem is that you are not passing the user that you want to delete when clicking:

users/_user.html.erb

```
<%= link_to "Destroy", user, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
```

See that in second param I added **user** instead of **user_url**.

users_controller.rb

```
 def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    if @user.destroy
        redirect_to root_url, notice: "User deleted."
    end
  end
```

In controller I removed an @user.destroy. You were calling it twice.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

At least the latest version of Devise **does** provide such functionality out of the box, if a Devise-backed model has `:registerable` included.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable
end
```

Somewhere in `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete my account', user_registration_path, method: :delete if user_signed_in? %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or from rails c you can do something like this where "x" is user id.

```
user = User.where(id: x)
user.destroy(1)
```