# Devise and CanCan cannot :destroy User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, authorization, cancan

I have an app that is using CacCan and Devise.  I am having Devise handle the User destroy action

The route

```
DELETE /users(.:format)    devise/registrations#destroy
```

My Controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!, :only => :portfolio

  def index
    redirect_to dashboard_user_path(current_user)
  end

  def dashboard
    ...
  end

  def portfolio
  end
end
```

My ability.rb

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new
    if user.role?('Administrator')
      can :access, :rails_admin
      can :dashboard
      can :manage, :all
    else
      cannot :destroy, User
      can :read, :all
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

This code above does not work.  A user who is not an administrator still has the ability to delete a user.  I am assuming the reason is that I do not have UsersController#destroy method.

So my question is, How do I make CanCan prevent a user who is not an administrator from being able to delete a user?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you defined abilities but not use them at all.

I suggest to read at least [this](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Authorizing-controller-actions) (gem has a reach wiki with very useful information so it worth to read all articles).
I prefer to use powerful `load_and_authorize_resource` but in you case maybe enough `authorize!` (code is NOT tested!)

```
def destroy
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  authorize! :destroy, @user
  ...
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I tried authorize! with load_and_authorize_resource and the delete still happen for a user that is not an admin.  I was wondering if there was a way to implement authorization on an action that is called from Devise.  The reason I say this is; I could create a method in my controller and a route for that method.  Then make the changes you suggested.  But it would not stop some one from running devise/registrations#destroy which would delete a user.

Comment: well I think (but I am not sure) that destroy route goes to another controller/action. I found several examples: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16289299/rails-how-to-destroy-users-created-under-devise) asserts that devise does not provide `destroy` action, [devise wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Disable-user-from-destroying-his-account) provides another example. I suggest to check if your action works when user destroys account - then debug ability else try to implement devise example and apply `authorize` there.

Comment: The first line in Devise::RegistrationsController#destroy is resource.destroy.  I believe this using my User#destroy method.  Not sure if I could use the first link, but the second link to the devise wiki seems promising.  I will take a look at that and let you know if it works.