# edit, delete user by id using devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, edit

I am building an admin panel where i created a page to list the users registered. I need to create a link to edit and delete a user by id. I don't know if devise allows such operations but maybe overwriting the original code..

here are my code on the view (not working of course):

```
%h2 Users
%table.table.table-striped
%thead
  %tr
    %th Name
    %th Email
    %th User Type
    %th Status
    %th Edit
    %th Delete
%tbody
  - @users.each do |user|
    %tr
      %th= user.name
      %th= user.email

      - if user.user_type == 1
        %th= user.user_type = "User"
      - else
        %th= user.user_type = "Admin"

      - if user.status == 1
        %th= user.status = "Active"
      - else
        %th= user.status = "Inactive"

      %th= link_to "<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></i>".html_safe, edit_user_registration_path(current_user), :method => :put
      %th= link_to "<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></i>".html_safe, registration_path(user), :confirm => "Are you sure?", :method => :delete
```

Comment: I think this post can help you. [destroy users created under devise](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16289299/rails-how-to-destroy-users-created-under-devise)